# Efficient way to find lots of "most recent" events in sqlite3

Tags: performance, select, sqlite

I've got an sqlite3 database that contains events.  Each event is either "on" or "off" of something happening, and contains the time of the event as well as what the event is and some miscellaneous data which varies by event.

I want to query to find that last event of each type.  So far this is the query I have come up with:

```
SELECT * from event where name='event1on' or name='event1off' ORDER BY t DESC LIMIT 1
```

This works, but it is slow when I have a lot of events I want to find the latest one of.  I suspect this is because for each SELECT a full scan of the database must be made (several million rows), but I am at a loss to find a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can use `max` to select other fields from the record that contains the maximum value:

```sql
SELECT *, max(t) FROM event GROUP BY name
```

To speed up this query, try creating one index on the `name` and `t` fields.

Comment: I tried `CREATE INDEX eventNameTimeIndex on event (name,t)` but it had no effect on query time.

Comment: It appears that, without the index, the query you suggested takes about the same amount of time as my query.  I like it as it is much more compact.  However, with the index, my query is about 40 times faster than the one you provided.